# Generate all possible n choose 2 pairs from a vector in R, efficient and fast

Tags: r

Imagine I have a vector x and i'd like to create a matrix with all the possible n choose 2 combinations of the elements of x.

More in detail, let us say x is,

```
x = c(1,2,3,4)
```

Then, all the possible (4 choose 2) = 6,

```
X = as.matrix(data.frame(col1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), col2 = c(2,3,4,3,4,4)))
```

Is there a function in R to do that?

Comment: Have a look at `?combn`.

Comment: More solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828301/faster-version-of-combn

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As pointed out by @Arun, you can use `combn`

```
> t(combn(x, 2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4
```