# Faster version of combn

Tags: r, data.table, combinations, combn

Is there a way to speed up the `combn` command to get all unique combinations of 2 elements taken from a vector?

Usually this would be set up like this:

```
# Get latest version of data.table
library(devtools)
install_github("Rdatatable/data.table",  build_vignettes = FALSE)  
library(data.table)

# Toy data
d <- data.table(id=as.character(paste0("A", 10001:15000))) 

# Transform data 
system.time({
d.1 <- as.data.table(t(combn(d$id, 2)))
})
```

However, `combn` is 10 times slower (23sec versus 3 sec on my computer) than calculating all possible combinations using data.table.

```
system.time({
d.2 <- d[, list(neighbor=d$id[-which(d$id==id)]), by=c("id")]
})
```

Dealing with very large vectors, I am searching for a way to save memory by only calculating the unique combinations (like `combn`), but with the speed of data.table (see second code snippet).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you installing `data.table` from github?

Comment: Because of a bug in 1.9.4 which will make problems when executing the second code snippet. However, this has already been corrected in 1.9.5.

Comment: Are you sure that `d.2 <- d[, list(neighbor=d$id[-which(d$id==id)]), by=c("id")]` gives you identical result to `d.1 <- as.data.table(t(combn(d$id, 2)))`? I'm getting twice as big data set. The way I could replicate `cmbn` with `data.table` is using `CJ`, something like `CJ(d$id, d$id), V1, V2)[V2 > V1]`

Comment: Correct. The dataset will be twice as large for the `data.table` code. By using this approach every combination is included twice. My question was on how to avoid the addition of those "duplicates" as this is critical if the vector gets large.

Comment: For every combination twice you could just do `CJ(d$id, d$id)`, which will ran less than a second

Comment: The code above does not include self-loops, whereas `CJ(d$id, d$id)` would include those. Sorry, if I failed to make this clear.

Comment: I meant that `d.2 <- d[, list(neighbor=d$id[-which(d$id==id)]), by=c("id")]` is equivalent to `CJ(d$id, d$id)`. While `d.1 <- as.data.table(t(combn(d$id, 2)))` is equalent to `CJ(d$id, d$id)[V2 > V1]`

Comment: Not exactly, `d.2 <- d[, list(neighbor=d$id[-which(d$id==id)]), by=c("id")]` and `CJ(d$id, d$id)` are not equivalent. The former does not include self-loops, whereas the latter does.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, `CJ(d$id, d$id)[V1 != V2]` would be equivalent, still twice as fast

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use [`combnPrim`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gRbase/docs/combnPrim) from [`gRbase`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRbase/index.html)

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("gRbase") # will install dependent packages automatically.
system.time({
 d.1 <- as.data.table(t(combn(d$id, 2)))
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
# 27.322   0.585  27.674 

system.time({
d.2 <- as.data.table(t(combnPrim(d$id,2)))
 })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.317   0.110   2.425 

identical(d.1[order(V1, V2),], d.2[order(V1,V2),])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'd suggest `https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R` instead of `http`, a bit safer.

Comment: by the way, why install from BioConductor rather than from CRAN? Was this function not available in the CRAN version at the time?

Comment: @Aurèle  The package was not based on CRAN repository.at the time I wrote the answer.  Now, I think it is the same as [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRbase/index.html)

Answer (score 23):

Here's a way using `data.table` function `foverlaps()`, that also turns out to be fast!

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.4+
d[, `:=`(id1 = 1L, id2 = .I)] ## add interval columns for overlaps
setkey(d, id1, id2)

system.time(olaps <- foverlaps(d, d, type="within", which=TRUE)[xid != yid])
#  0.603   0.062   0.717
```

Note that `foverlaps()` *does not* calculate all permutations. The subset `xid != yid` is needed to remove *self overlaps*. The subset could be internally handled more efficiently by implementing `ignoreSelf` argument - similar to `IRanges::findOverlaps`.

Now it's just a matter of performing a subset using the ids obtained:

```
system.time(ans <- setDT(list(d$id[olaps$xid], d$id[olaps$yid])))
#   0.576   0.047   0.662
```

So totally, ~1.4 seconds.

---

The advantage is that you can do the same way even if your data.table `d` has more than 1 column on which you've to get the combinations for, and using the same amount of memory (since we return the indices). In that case, you'd just do:

```
cbind(d[olaps$xid, ..your_cols], d[olaps$yid, ..your_cols])
```

But it's limited to replacing just `combn(., 2L)`. Not more than 2L.

Comment: Wow, that came out very fast. I was trying doing it with `CJ`, but it was much slower, something like `ans <- setkey(CJ(d$id, d$id), V1, V2)[V2 > V1]`

Comment: `CJ` already sorts. So you don't ned `setkey` around it. And `CJ(d$id, d$id)` should be fast (takes 0.9 seconds on mine). But it's the subset that seems costly, as `CJ` returns all permutations, unlike `foverlaps()`.

Comment: Yeah, `CJ(d$id, d$id)` is fast, the `[V2 > V1]` part is what taking it so long (~9 secs). I wonder why `[xid != yid]` in your code doesn't have same effect. Probably because it has less values

Comment: Fwiw, this is also fairly fast: `system.time(res <- d[, r := .I ][d, on=.(r > r), nomatch=0] )` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/43315317/

Answer (score 14):

A post with any variation of the word ***Fast*** in the title is incomplete without benchmarks. Before we post any benchmarks, I would just like to mention that since this question was posted, two highly optimized packages, `arrangements` and `RcppAlgos` (I am the author) for generating combinations have been released for `R`. Note that since version `2.3.0` for `RcppAlgos` we can take advantage of multiple threads for even greater efficiency.

To give you an idea of their speed over `combn` and `gRbase::combnPrim`, here is a basic benchmark:

```
## We test generating just over 3 million combinations
choose(25, 10)
[1] 3268760

microbenchmark(arrngmnt = arrangements::combinations(25, 10),
               combn = combn(25, 10),
               gRBase = gRbase::combnPrim(25, 10),
               serAlgos = RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(25, 10),
               parAlgos = RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(25, 10, nThreads = 4),
               unit = "relative", times = 20)
Unit: relative
    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
arrngmnt   2.979378   3.072319   1.898390   3.756307   2.139258  0.4842967    20
   combn 226.470755 230.410716 118.157110 232.905393 125.718512 17.7778585    20
  gRBase  34.219914  34.209820  18.789954  34.218320  19.934485  3.6455493    20
serAlgos   2.836651   3.078791   2.458645   3.703929   2.231475  1.1652445    20
parAlgos   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000  1.0000000    20
```

Now, we benchmark the other functions posted for the very specific case of producing combinations choose 2 and producing a `data.table` object.

The functions are as follows:

```
funAkraf <- function(d) {
    a <- comb2.int(length(d$id))      ## comb2.int from the answer given by @akraf
    setDT(list(V1 = d$id[a[,1]], V2 = d$id[a[,2]]))
}

funAnirban <- function(d) {
    indices <- combi2inds(d$id)
    ans2 <- setDT(list(d$id[indices$xid], d$id[indices$yid]))
    ans2
}

funArun <- function(d) {
    d[, `:=`(id1 = 1L, id2 = .I)] ## add interval columns for overlaps
    setkey(d, id1, id2)
    olaps <- foverlaps(d, d, type="within", which=TRUE)[xid != yid]
    ans <- setDT(list(d$id[olaps$xid], d$id[olaps$yid]))
    ans
}

funArrangements <- function(d) {
  a <- arrangements::combinations(x = d$id, k = 2)
  setDT(list(a[, 1], a[, 2]))
}

funGRbase <- function(d) {
  a <- gRbase::combnPrim(d$id,2)
  setDT(list(a[1, ], a[2, ]))
}

funOPCombn <- function(d) {
  a <- combn(d$id, 2)
  setDT(list(a[1, ], a[2, ]))
}

funRcppAlgos <- function(d) {
  a <- RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(d$id, 2, nThreads = 4)
  setDT(list(a[, 1], a[, 2]))
}
```

#### Benchmark with OP Data

And here are the benchmarks on the example given by the OP:

```
d <- data.table(id=as.character(paste0("A", 10001:15000))) 

microbenchmark(funAkraf(d),
               funAnirban(d),
               funArrangements(d),
               funArun(d),
               funGRbase(d),
               funOPCombn(d),
               funRcppAlgos(d),
               times = 10, unit = "relative")
    Unit: relative
              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
       funAkraf(d)  3.220550  2.971264  2.815023  2.665616  2.344018  3.383673    10
     funAnirban(d)  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    10
funArrangements(d)  1.464730  1.689231  1.834650  1.960233  1.932361  1.693305    10
        funArun(d)  3.256889  2.908075  2.634831  2.729180  2.432277  2.193849    10
      funGRbase(d)  3.513847  3.340637  3.327845  3.196399  3.291480  3.129362    10
     funOPCombn(d) 30.310469 26.255374 21.656376 22.386270 18.527904 15.626261    10
   funRcppAlgos(d)  1.676808  1.956696  1.943773  2.085968  1.949133  1.804180    10
```

We see that the function provided by @AnirbanMukherjee is the fastest for this task, followed by `RcppAlgos`/`arrangements`. For this task, `nThreads` has no effect as the vector passed is a `character`, which is not thread safe. What if we instead converted `id` to a factor?

#### Benchmarks with Factors (i.e. Categorical Variables)

```
dFac <- d
dFac$id <- as.factor(dFac$id)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funAkraf(dFac),
               funAnirban(dFac),
               funArrangements(dFac),
               funArun(dFac),
               funGRbase(dFac),
               funOPCombn(dFac),
               funRcppAlgos(dFac),
               times = 10, unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
                 expr        min         lq      mean   median        uq       max   neval
       funAkraf(dFac)  10.898202  10.949896  7.589814 10.01369  8.050005  5.557014      10
     funAnirban(dFac)   3.104212   3.337344  2.317024  3.00254  2.471887  1.530978      10
funArrangements(dFac)   2.054116   2.058768  1.858268  1.94507  2.797956  1.691875      10
        funArun(dFac)  10.646680  12.905119  7.703085 11.50311  8.410893  3.802155      10
      funGRbase(dFac)  16.523356  21.609917 12.991400 19.73776 13.599870  6.498135      10
     funOPCombn(dFac) 108.301876 108.753085 64.338478 95.56197 65.494335 28.183104      10
   funRcppAlgos(dFac)   1.000000   1.000000  1.000000  1.00000  1.000000  1.000000      10
```

Now, we see that `RcppAlgos` is around `2x` faster than any other solution. In particular, the `RcppAlgos` solution is about **`3x`** than the formerly fastest solution given by Anirban. It should be noted that this increase in efficiency was possible because `factor` variables are really `integers` underneath the hood with some additional `attributes`.

#### Confirm Equality

They all give the same result as well. The only caveat is that the `gRbase` solution doesn't support factors. That is, if you pass a `factor`, it will be converted to `character`. Thus all of the solutions will give the same result if you were to pass `dFac` except for the `gRbase` solution:

```
identical(funAkraf(d), funOPCombn(d))
#[1] TRUE
identical(funAkraf(d), funArrangements(d))
#[1] TRUE
identical(funRcppAlgos(d), funArrangements(d))
#[1] TRUE
identical(funRcppAlgos(d), funAnirban(d))
#[1] TRUE
identical(funRcppAlgos(d), funArun(d))
#[1] TRUE

## different order... we must sort
identical(funRcppAlgos(d), funGRbase(d))
[1] FALSE
d1 <- funGRbase(d)
d2 <- funRcppAlgos(d)

## now it's the same
identical(d1[order(V1, V2),], d2[order(V1,V2),])
#[1] TRUE
```

Thanks to @Frank for pointing out how to compare two `data.tables` without going through the pains of creating new `data.tables` and then arranging them:

```
fsetequal(funRcppAlgos(d), funGRbase(d))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Fyi, for order-agnostic comparison: `DT = data.table(a = 1:2); fsetequal(DT, DT[2:1])`

Comment: Approx. 64% of the time on my computer in the above benchmarks is spent outside of combi2inds to execute `setDT(list(d$id[indices$xid], d$id[indices$yid]))`. This is needed if `d$id` is a character vector but is not necessarily needed if `d$id` is an integer/factor. In the latter case, the indices are the output values if the factor variable is coded from 1 onwards and all levels are passed to the function. This is trivially achieved by recoding a factor variable prior to calling the function.

Comment: E.g., if d$id is a factor then `combi2inds(factor(as.character(d$id)))` should always work to generate an output where `xid` and `yid` are the two columns of the data frame with the integer values corresponding to the new factor variable `factor(as.character(d$id))`. I don't know any way to seamlessly make a new factor variable from an integer variable by only passing the levels as a character vector but if that were possible then the algorithm would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution using Rcpp.

```
library(Rcpp)
library(data.table)
cppFunction('
Rcpp::DataFrame combi2(Rcpp::CharacterVector inputVector){
    int len = inputVector.size();
    int retLen = len * (len-1) / 2;
    Rcpp::CharacterVector outputVector1(retLen);
    Rcpp::CharacterVector outputVector2(retLen);
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        for (int j = i+1; j < len; ++j){
            outputVector1(start) = inputVector(i);
            outputVector2(start) = inputVector(j);
            ++start;
            }
        }
    return(Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::Named("id") = outputVector1,
                              Rcpp::Named("neighbor") = outputVector2));
};
')

# Toy data
d <- data.table(id=as.character(paste0("A", 10001:15000))) 

system.time({
    d.2 <- d[, list(neighbor=d$id[-which(d$id==id)]), by=c("id")]
    })
#  1.908   0.397   2.389

system.time({
    d[, `:=`(id1 = 1L, id2 = .I)] ## add interval columns for overlaps
    setkey(d, id1, id2)
    olaps <- foverlaps(d, d, type="within", which=TRUE)[xid != yid]
    ans <- setDT(list(d$id[olaps$xid], d$id[olaps$yid]))
    })
#  0.653   0.038   0.705

system.time(ans2 <- combi2(d$id))
#  1.377   0.108   1.495
```

Using the Rcpp function to get the indices and then form the data.table, works better.

```
cppFunction('
Rcpp::DataFrame combi2inds(const Rcpp::CharacterVector inputVector){
const int len = inputVector.size();
const int retLen = len * (len-1) / 2;
Rcpp::IntegerVector outputVector1(retLen);
Rcpp::IntegerVector outputVector2(retLen);
int indexSkip;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
    indexSkip = len * i - ((i+1) * i)/2;
    for (int j = 0; j < len-1-i; ++j){
        outputVector1(indexSkip+j) = i+1;
        outputVector2(indexSkip+j) = i+j+1+1;
        }
    }
return(Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::Named("xid") = outputVector1,
                          Rcpp::Named("yid") = outputVector2));
};
')

system.time({
        indices <- combi2inds(d$id)
        ans2 <- setDT(list(d$id[indices$xid], d$id[indices$yid]))
        })      
#  0.389   0.027   0.425
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are two base-R solutions if  you don't want to use additional dependencies:

- `comb2.int` uses `rep` and other sequence generating functions to generate the desired output.
- `comb2.mat` creates a matrix, uses `upper.tri()` to get the upper triangle and `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)` to obtain the column and row indices => all combinations.

#### Possibility 1: `comb2.int`

```r
comb2.int <- function(n, rep = FALSE){
  if(!rep){
    # e.g. n=3 => (1,2), (1,3), (2,3)
    x <- rep(1:n,(n:1)-1)
    i <- seq_along(x)+1
    o <- c(0,cumsum((n-2):1))
    y <- i-o[x]
  }else{
    # e.g. n=3 => (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)
    x <- rep(1:n,n:1)
    i <- seq_along(x)
    o <- c(0,cumsum(n:2))
    y <- i-o[x]+x-1
  }
  return(cbind(x,y))
}
```

#### Possibility 2: `comb2.mat`

```r
comb2.mat <- function(n, rep = FALSE){
  # Use which(..., arr.ind = TRUE) to get coordinates.
  m <- matrix(FALSE, nrow = n, ncol = n)
  idxs <- which(upper.tri(m, diag = rep), arr.ind = TRUE)
  return(idxs)
}
```

#### The functions give the same result as `combn(.)`:

```r
for(i in 2:8){
  # --- comb2.int ------------------
  stopifnot(comb2.int(i) == t(combn(i,2)))
  # => Equal

  # --- comb2.mat ------------------
  m <- comb2.mat(i)
  colnames(m) <- NULL   # difference 1: colnames
  m <- m[order(m[,1]),] # difference 2: output order
  stopifnot(m == t(combn(i,2)))
  # => Equal up to above differences
}
```

#### But I have other elements in my vector than sequencial integers!

Use the return values as indices:

```r
v <- LETTERS[1:5]                                     
c <- comb2.int(length(v))                             
cbind(v[c[,1]], v[c[,2]])                             
#>       [,1] [,2]
#>  [1,] "A"  "B" 
#>  [2,] "A"  "C" 
#>  [3,] "A"  "D" 
#>  [4,] "A"  "E" 
#>  [5,] "B"  "C" 
#>  [6,] "B"  "D" 
#>  [7,] "B"  "E" 
#>  [8,] "C"  "D" 
#>  [9,] "C"  "E" 
#> [10,] "D"  "E"
```

#### Benchmark:

time(`combn`) = ~5x time(`comb2.mat`) = ~80x time(`comb2.int`):

```r
library(microbenchmark)

n <- 800
microbenchmark({
  comb2.int(n)
},{
  comb2.mat(n)
},{
  t(combn(n, 2))
})
#>   Unit: milliseconds
#>                    expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#>    {     comb2.int(n) }   4.394051   4.731737   6.350406   5.334463   7.22677  14.68808   100
#>    {     comb2.mat(n) }  20.131455  22.901534  31.648521  24.411782  26.95821 297.70684   100
#>  {     t(combn(n, 2)) } 363.687284 374.826268 391.038755 380.012274 389.59960 532.30305   100
```

Comment: I think your comments are backwards in `comb2.int`. You have in the repetition block, `# e.g. n=3 => (1,2), (1,3), (2,3)`, when it should be `# e.g. n=3 => (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3)` and vice versa.

Comment: @JosephWood you're right, thx. Edited to fix.