# Generate all possible binary vectors of length n in R

Tags: r, vector, binary

I'm looking to generate all possible binary vectors of length `n` in R. What is the best way (preferably both computationally efficient and readable code) to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
n = 3
expand.grid(replicate(n, 0:1, simplify = FALSE))
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    0    0    0
#2    1    0    0
#3    0    1    0
#4    1    1    0
#5    0    0    1
#6    1    0    1
#7    0    1    1
#8    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826508/create-all-possible-combiations-of-0-1-or-2-1s-of-a-binary-vector-of-length-n) generating all possible binary vectors of length `n` containing *less than* `m` 1s, I've extended this code to produce all possible combinations. It's not pretty, though.

```
> z <- 3
> z <- rep(0, n)
> do.call(rbind, lapply(0:n, function(i) t(apply(combn(1:n,i), 2, function(k) {z[k]=1;z}))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    1
[5,]    1    1    0
[6,]    1    0    1
[7,]    0    1    1
[8,]    1    1    1
```

What is it doing? Once we strip it back, the core of this one-liner is the following:

```
apply(combn(1:n,i), 2, function(k) {z[k]=1;z})
```

To understand this, let's step back one level further. The function `combn(x,m)` generates all possible combinations of `x` taken `m` at a time.

```
> combn(1:n, 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
> combn(1:n, 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    3    3
> combn(1:n, 3)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

For using `apply(MARGIN=2)`, we pass in a column of this function at a time to our inner function `function(k) {z[k]=1;z}` which simply replaces all of the values at the indices `k` with `1`. Since they were originally all `0`, this gives us each possible binary vector.

The rest is just window dressing. `combn` gives us a wide, short matrix; we transpose it with `t`. `lapply` returns a list; we bind the matrices in each element of the list together with `do.call(rbind, .)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should define what is "the best way" (fastest? shortest code?, etc.).

One way is to use the package `R.utils` and the function `intToBin` for converting decimal numbers to binary numbers. See the example.

```
require(R.utils)
n <- 5
strsplit(intToBin(0:(2 ^ n - 1)), split = "")
```