# How can I generate all the possible combinations of a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector, say `A,B,C,D,E` and I am interested in generating all the possible combination of the vector elements. The desired output is given below.

`B-A`,`C-A`,`D-A`,`E-A`,`C-B`,`D-B`,`E-B`,`D-C`,`E-C`,`E-D`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
combn(v1, 2, FUN=function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse="-"))
#[1] "B-A" "C-A" "D-A" "E-A" "C-B" "D-B" "E-B" "D-C" "E-C" "E-D"
```

If you want in the default order

```
combn(v1, 2, FUN=paste, collapse="-")
#[1] "A-B" "A-C" "A-D" "A-E" "B-C" "B-D" "B-E" "C-D" "C-E" "D-E"
```

#### Update

For a faster option, you can use `combnPrim` from `grBase`.  Check [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828301/faster-version-of-combn/26828486#26828486)

```
library(grBase) 
apply(combnPrim(v1,2), 2, FUN=paste, collapse='-')
#[1] "A-B" "A-C" "B-C" "A-D" "B-D" "C-D" "A-E" "B-E" "C-E" "D-E"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- LETTERS[1:5]
```

Comment: Just do `combn(v1, 2, FUN=paste, collapse="-")`

Comment: What if I want both, for example, A-B, B-A.

Comment: @AwaitedOne For that you an use `expand.grid` or `outer`

Comment: @akrun Do you mean something like `grep('(.*)-\\1', unique(as.vector(outer(unique_conds, unique_conds,
                                                             FUN = paste, sep = '-' ))), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)` as suggested by @agstudy. But it does not give appropriate output for `v1 <- c("A", "Aa", "B")` because `"A-Aa" ` is missing, may be issue with the regular expression.

Comment: @AwaitedOne  Not sure.  May be you need to post a new question

Answer (score 4):

`combn` is the classic way to go. But  it is generally slow ( it is entirely written in R). Here another option that I believe much faster:

```
grep('(.)-\\1',unique(as.vector(outer(v1,v1,FUN=paste,sep='-'))),
     value=TRUE,invert=TRUE)
```

In case you have more than one characters, the regex becomes:

```
  (.*)-\\1
```

1. I used the vectorized `outer`  to create all combinations
2. Then I removed duplicated characters using some regular expressions.

This gives all combinations and its reverse orders:

### edit some benchamrks:

```
v1 <- LETTERS
fun_agstudy <- function()
grep('(.)-\\1',unique(as.vector(outer(v1,v1,FUN=paste,sep='-'))),
     value=TRUE,invert=TRUE)
fun_akrun <- function()
combn(v1, 2, FUN=function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse="-"))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun_agstudy(),fun_akrun())
```

[image]

```
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
1 fun_agstudy()  692.149  707.509 1082.153  774.259  956.114 25818.46   100
2   fun_akrun() 6597.217 6681.982 8076.223 6765.040 9020.306 36364.15   100
```

### edit2 using bioclite:

`outer` still a little bit faster

```
summary(microbenchmark(fun_agstudy(),fun_akrun(),fun_combnPrim()))
             expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
1   fun_agstudy()  700.114  735.3845  801.3568  786.2055  810.288  2572.896   100
2     fun_akrun() 6830.082 6929.2590 9030.9779 7040.5720 7498.717 62051.764   100
3 fun_combnPrim() 1928.534 1985.9925 2407.1335 2035.8655 2176.191 28514.237   100
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to add some benchmark to support your assertion.

Comment: I think it gives all the combinations `A-B` and its reverse order i,e `B-A`

Comment: Try with `combnPrim`.  Also, I don't know whether you used the small vector for benchmarks.

Comment: @akrun `outer` and `mapply` are generally very efficient. Even, if here I should tune the regex to remove duplicated pairs as asked in the OP.

Comment: @agstudy, i tried with `v1 <- c("C","Tu")`, result comes `"Tu-C"  "C-Tu"  "Tu-Tu"`, how ??

Comment: @AaghazHussain  You may need to change the regex part

Comment: Try this `grep('(.*)-\\1',unique(as.vector(outer(v1,v1,FUN=paste,sep='-'))),
         value=TRUE,invert=TRUE)` Note , In your question you asked for a single characters.

Comment: @agstudy Regarding getting all the combinations and removing the duplicate elements  Arun's answer with data.table may be faster in the link I provided below.

Comment: Akrun I didn't try. But I think you are right,  `fovarlaps` and ( @Arun) are generally amazingly efficient :)

Comment: Why it does not return the combinations as expected for `v1 <- c("Testis_NOA_ID","Testis_NOA_IDSt")`. it returns `"Testis_NOA_ID-Testis_NOA_IDSt"` only but I am expecting  `"Testis_NOA_IDSt-Testis_NOA_ID"` also.