# Generate all the possible combinations of a vector

Tags: r, vector, combinations

I am interested to generate all the possible combinations of a vector, for example,

```
v1 <- c("A", "Aa", "B")
```

and all the possible combinations will be

```
"A-Aa" "Aa-A" "B-A"  "B-Aa" "A-B"  "Aa-B"
```

I saw a post- [How can I generate all the possible combinations of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995533/how-can-i-generate-all-the-possible-combinations-of-a-vector/30995574?noredirect=1#comment84705944_30995574), but it does not give correct results for `v1`. The same thing happens to `v1 <- c("Testis_NOA_ID","Testis_NOA_IDSt")` which returns `"Testis_NOA_ID-Testis_NOA_IDSt"` only but I am expecting `"Testis_NOA_IDSt-Testis_NOA_ID"` also.

I checked some other vectors such as `v1 <- c("a,"b","c)` or `v1 <- c("normal", "cancer")`, which it gives correct results. The problem comes when the vector content is repeating like `v1 <- c("Testis_NOA_ID","Testis_NOA_IDSt")`. How to fix it.

Comment: You need `res <- outer(v1, v1, FUN = paste, sep="-");
res[row(res) != col(res)]`

Comment: Great!!, Can u please tell how it works?

Comment: As I mentioned in the other post, `outer` gives all the combinations, by specifying the `FUN` as `paste`, you get the concatenated combinations of the vector elements in a `matrix`.  Based on your expected output, the same element combinations are removed which happens to be on the diagonal and that elements are removed with `row(res) != col(res)`