# Intersecting many pairs of integer vectors

Tags: r, list, intersection, combn

I have a `list` of `integer` `vector`s:

```
set.seed(1)
l <- list(g1=as.integer(runif(10,1,100)),
          g2=as.integer(runif(5,1,100)),
          g3=as.integer(runif(5,1,100)),
          g4=as.integer(runif(8,1,100)))
```

(in reality it's 1000's elements long and the mean length of the vector elements is in the 100s)

I want to compute the `intersection` over the `union` between all pairs of `l`'s elements and their corresponding `hypergeometric`/`fisher.test` `p-value`.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

1. First I generate a matrix to store `l` indices of all pairs of its elements:

   ```
   idx.mat <- t(combn(1:length(l),2))
   ```

This part is pretty fast and can be made faster using [combnPrim](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gRbase/docs/combnPrim)

2. Then I run this function to get my desired output:

   `res.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(idx.mat), function(i){
     gi.length <- length(l[[idx.mat[i,1]]])
     gj.length <- length(l[[idx.mat[i,2]]])
     set.diff.1 <- length(setdiff(l[[idx.mat[i,1]]],l[[idx.mat[i,2]]]))
     set.diff.2 <- length(setdiff(l[[idx.mat[i,2]]],l[[idx.mat[i,1]]]))
     gi.gj.inter <- length(intersect(l[[idx.mat[i,1]]],l[[idx.mat[i,2]]]))
     gi.gj.union <- length(unique(c(l[[idx.mat[i,1]]],l[[idx.mat[i,2]]])))
     p.value <- fisher.test(matrix(c(gi.length+gj.length-    gi.gj.union,set.diff.1,set.diff.2,gi.gj.inter),nrow=2),alternative="greater")$p.value
     return(data.frame(gi=names(l)[idx.mat[i,1]],
                       gj=names(l)[idx.mat[i,2]],
                       gi.gj.inter=gi.gj.inter,
                       gi.gj.union=gi.gj.union,
                       gi.gj.iou=gi.gj.inter/gi.gj.union,
                       gi.gj.iou.p.val=p.value,
                       stringsAsFactors=F))
   }))`

But for my real data size this is a bit slow.

Any idea how to achieve this faster?

Comment: Which part of my example data is not small or reproducible?

Comment: @dan Your example is fine.  It is just that somebody didn't read it properly :-)

Comment: For your specific question, one option is `combnPrim` as showed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828301/faster-version-of-combn)

Comment: @akrun, the combn part is not the bottle neck. Computing the intersection over the union and the hypergeometric p-value between each pair is the problem. I edited my question to make this clear

Comment: How come `m`, `n` and `k` parameters of the hypergeomtric distribution are `length(l[[idx.mat[i,1]]])`,                                      `length(l[[idx.mat[i,1]]])+length(l[[idx.mat[i,2]]])` and                                              `length(l[[idx.mat[i,2]]]))`, can you explain?

Comment: I changed it to fisher.test. The problem is still the time this takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try representing `l` as a 1/0 matrix:

```
max.val = max(sapply(l, max))
mat = do.call(rbind, lapply(l, function(x) {z = rep(0, max.val); z[x] = 1; z}))
```

Now you can easily compute the pairwise intersections and unions up front:

```
pair_intsct = mat %*% t(mat)

pair_union = outer(rowSums(mat), rowSums(mat), '+') - pair_intsct
```