# How to select unique point

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations

I am a novice R programmer. I have a following series of points.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1 , 2, 3, 4), y = c(6 , 3, 7, 5))
df <- df %>% mutate(k = 1) 
df <- df %>% full_join(df, by = 'k')
df <- subset(df, select = c('x.x', 'y.x', 'x.y', 'y.y'))
df
```

Is there way to select for "unique" points? (the order of the points do not matter)

EDIT:

```
x.x y.x x.y y.y
1   6   2   3
2   3   3   7
.
.
.
```

(I changed the 2 to 7 to clarify the problem)

Comment: My expected output would be 6 rows (4 choose 2) of the combinations of all the points. I'll make an edit.

Comment: should all 4 values in on line to be taken inaccount? or only one x and y value?

Comment: My "objects" for my 4 choose 2 problem should be the point pairs 'x.x' and 'y.x'

Comment: By the way, overwriting `df` like that, especially as part of an example, is not generally a good idea. You'll see that the answers below use different `df`s per your differing definitions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With data.table (and working from the OP's initial `df`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, r := .I ]
df[df, on=.(r > r), nomatch=0]


   x y r i.x i.y
1: 2 3 1   1   6
2: 3 2 1   1   6
3: 4 5 1   1   6
4: 3 2 2   2   3
5: 4 5 2   2   3
6: 4 5 3   3   2
```

This is a "non-equi join" on row numbers. In `x[i, on=.(r > r)]` the left-hand `r` refers to the row in `x` and the right-hand one to a row of `i`. The columns named like `i.*` are taken from `i`.

Data.table joins, which are of the form `x[i]`, use `i` to look up rows of `x`. The `nomatch=0` option drops rows of `i` that find no matches.

Comment: Oh, that's just creating the row number, same as `mutate(r = row_number())` in dplyr, except it adds it to the table by reference, so there's no need to assign the result with `<-`.

Comment: Ohhh you are doing a non equi join on the data set. through data.table

Comment: @NicholasHayden Fwiw, I don't know enough SQL to know what a non equi join is beyond use through data.table :)

Answer (score 2):

In the tidyverse, you can save a bit of work by doing the self-join with `tidyr::crossing`. If you add row indices pre-join, reducing is a simple `filter` call:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(i = row_number()) %>%    # add row index column
    crossing(., .) %>%    # Cartesian self-join
    filter(i < i1) %>%    # reduce to lower indices
    select(-i, -i1)    # remove extraneous columns

##   x y x1 y1
## 1 1 6  2  3
## 2 1 6  3  7
## 3 1 6  4  5
## 4 2 3  3  7
## 5 2 3  4  5
## 6 3 7  4  5
```

or in all base R,

```
df$m <- 1
df$i <- seq(nrow(df))
df <- merge(df, df, by = 'm')
df[df$i.x < df$i.y, c(-1, -4, -7)]

##    x.x y.x x.y y.y
## 2    1   6   2   3
## 3    1   6   3   7
## 4    1   6   4   5
## 7    2   3   3   7
## 8    2   3   4   5
## 12   3   7   4   5
```

Comment: For base R, also: `cb = combn(nrow(df), 2); cbind(df[cb[1,],], df[cb[2,],])`

Comment: I am getting an error with the dplyr method. It says they are duplicated columns when it gets to the filter step. Is there a way to differientiate the columns?

Comment: @Frank Yeah, that's a much more straightforward option.

Comment: @NicholasHayden Ah, this is on the devel versions of dplyr (probably doesn't matter) and tidyr. I believe the CRAN version of tidyr does not clean duplicate names automatically, but the GitHub version does. If you don't want to update, you could fix them manually with `... %>% setNames(make.names(names(.), unique = TRUE)) %>% ...`, adjusting subsequent names as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `duplicated.matrix()` function from base, to find the rows which are no duplicator - which means in fact that there are unique. When you call the `duplicated()` function you have to clarify that you only want to use the to first colons. With this call you check which line is unique. In a second step you call in your dataframe for this rows, with all columns.

```
unique_lines = !duplicated.matrix(df[,c(1,2)])
df[unique_lines,]
```