# Optimizing calculation of combinations into list - large data set

Tags: r, optimization, combinations

I wonder if someone can figure out a faster way to calculate combinations of elements in vector. My approach works but is slow with about 6 million elements in the vector.

**Test vector**

```
test.vector <- c("335261 344015 537633","22404 132858","254654 355860 488288","219943 373817","331839 404477")
```

**My approach**

```
lapply(strsplit(test.vector, " "), function(x) unique(apply(combn(x, 2), 2, function(y) paste0(y, collapse = ""))))
```

**Expected output**

```
[[1]]
[1] "335261344015" "335261537633" "344015537633"

[[2]]
[1] "22404132858"

[[3]]
[1] "254654355860" "254654488288" "355860488288"

[[4]]
[1] "219943373817"

[[5]]
[1] "331839404477"
```

Comment: first quick thing is to add fixed = TRUE to strsplit

Comment: also, combn is written in R and hence slow. see here https://stackoverflow.com/q/26828301/3576984

Comment: wow thanks that should already boost the whole thing!

Comment: You can also use `parLapply()` to improve performance (not by a lot depending on how many clusters you can use).

Comment: `Map(combn,strsplit(test.vector, " "),2,c(paste0),collapse="")?`or even  `lapply(strsplit(test.vector, " "),combn,2,paste0,collapse="")`? you are using `apply` inside the `lapply` function.. this reduces the speed

Comment: To include the uniqueness, you can do `lapply(strsplit(test.vector, " "),function(x) combn(unique(x),2,paste0,collapse=""))`

Comment: also I highly recommend rstudios's built in code profiler, which will quickly show to your your code's bottlenecks

Comment: Is there a limit on our numbers? For example, can the individual numbers before they are split be greater than say 10^7? Are you going to use the results computationally?

Comment: @JosephWood yes, they go up to about 600000 and I use the results for subsequent calculations

Comment: @Onyambu for my whole dataset I run into > Error in combn(unique(x), 2, paste0, collapse = "") : n < m with the `lapply(strsplit(test.vector, " "),function(x) combn(unique(x),2,paste0,collapse=""))`

Comment: That is because you end up with a vector that has no data or just 1 number... If you look at your function, unique was applied AFTER the combination had been done... so you can try that one `lapply(strsplit(test.vector, " "),function(x) unique(combn(x,2,paste0,collapse="")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer that is over `25x` faster than the OP's solution on large test cases. It doesn't rely on `paste`, but rather we take advantage of properties of numbers and vectorized operations.  We also use `comboGeneral` from the `RcppAlgos` package (I am the author) which is much faster than `combn` and `combnPrim` from the linked answer for generating combinations of a vector. First we show the efficiency gains of `comboGeneral` over the other functions:

```
## library(gRbase)
library(RcppAlgos)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(gRbase::combnPrim(300, 2), combn(300, 2), 
               comboGeneral(300, 2), unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
                     expr        min         lq      mean     median         uq       max neval
gRbase::combnPrim(300, 2)   5.145654   5.192439   4.83561   7.167839   4.320497   3.98992   100
            combn(300, 2) 204.866624 192.559119 143.75540 174.079339 102.733367 539.12325   100
     comboGeneral(300, 2)   1.000000   1.000000   1.00000   1.000000   1.000000   1.00000   100
```

Now, we create a function to create some random reproducible data that will be passed to our test functions:

```
makeTestSet <- function(vectorSize, elementSize, mySeed = 42, withRep = FALSE) {
    set.seed(mySeed)
    sapply(1:vectorSize, function(x) {
        paste(sample(10^6, s1 <- sample(2:elementSize, 1), replace = withRep), collapse = " ")
    })
}

makeTestSet(5, 3)
[1] "937076 286140 830446" "519096 736588 134667" "705065 457742 719111" 
[4] "255429 462293 940013" "117488 474997 560332"
```

That looks good. Now, lets see if setting `fixed = TRUE` gets us any gains (as suggested above by @MichaelChirico):

```
bigVec <- makeTestSet(10, 100000)

microbenchmark(standard = strsplit(bigVec, " "), 
               withFixed = strsplit(bigVec, " ", fixed = TRUE), 
               times = 15, unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 standard 4.447413 4.296662 4.133797 4.339537 4.084019 3.415639    15
withFixed 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    15
```

@MichaelChirico was spot on. Putting it all together we get:

```
combPairFast <- function(testVec) {
    lapply(strsplit(testVec, " ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) {
        combs <- RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(as.numeric(x), 2)
        unique(combs[,1] * (10)^(as.integer(log10(combs[,2])) + 1L) + combs[,2])
    })
}

## test.vector defined above by OP
combPairFast(test.vector)
[[1]]
[1] 335261344015 335261537633 344015537633

[[2]]
[1] 22404132858

[[3]]
[1] 254654355860 254654488288 355860488288

[[4]]
[1] 219943373817

[[5]]
[1] 331839404477

## OP original code
combPairOP <- function(testVec) {
    lapply(strsplit(testVec, " "), function(x) unique(apply(combn(x, 2), 2, function(y) paste0(y, collapse = ""))))
}
```

As stated in the comments by the OP, the maximum number is less than a million (600000 to be exact), which means that after we multiply one of the numbers by at most 10^6 and add it to another 6 digit number (equivalent to simply concatenating two strings of numbers), we are guaranteed to be within the numerical precision of base R (i.e. `2^53 - 1`). This is good because arithmetic operations on numerical numbers is much more efficient than strings operations.

All that is left is to benchmark:

```
test.vector <- makeTestSet(100, 50)

microbenchmark(combPairOP(test.vector), 
               combPairFast(test.vector),
               times = 20, unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
                     expr      min      lq     mean   median     uq      max neval
  combPairOP(test.vector) 22.33991 22.4264 21.67291 22.11017 21.729 25.23342    20
combPairFast(test.vector)  1.00000  1.0000  1.00000  1.00000  1.000  1.00000    20
```

And on larger vectors:

```
bigTest.vector <- makeTestSet(1000, 100, mySeed = 22, withRep = TRUE)

## Duplicate values exist
any(sapply(strsplit(bigTest.vector, " ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) {
    any(duplicated(x))
}))
[1] TRUE

system.time(t1 <- combPairFast(bigTest.vector))
 user  system elapsed 
0.303   0.011   0.314 

system.time(t2 <- combPairOP(bigTest.vector))
 user  system elapsed 
8.820   0.081   8.902    ### 8.902 / 0.314 ~= 28x faster

## results are the same
all.equal(t1, lapply(t2, as.numeric))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Yours runs super fast but I can't get the results all.equal TRUE with your outcome and mine using my old code `lapply(strsplit(df$full.number, " ",fixed = T), function(x)
  unique(apply(combn(x, 2), 2, function(y) paste0(y, collapse = ""))))`

Comment: Are you sorting and converting to numeric as I did in the example above?

Comment: yes, just guessing but is the unique missing maybe?

Comment: @CER, That is exactly what I was about to write... If you do unique (as.numeric(x)) it should work. I will update my answer when I get a chance, but the idea still holds. That is, arithmetic is faster than paste.

Comment: Maybe I just doing something wrong but even just using your `combPair()` and `combPairfast()` and your `bigTest.vector`and than running the all.equal() does not give me a TRUE. `set.seed(22)`

Comment: @CER, I just saw your comments.... I reran with `set.seed(22)` and when I run `all.equal(lapply(t1, sort), lapply(t2, function(x) sort(as.numeric(x))))`, it returns `TRUE`. I'm not sure what you are doing, but there is no way to know unless you post a specific example where the solutions differ.  I still haven't forgotten about updating to account for non-unique values (doing it right now).