# R - Fastest way to make an edgelist from data.frame in long format

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I'm looking for a fast and scalable solution to coerce a massive data.frame from a long format to an edgelist in R.

Consider the following data.frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c("A1", "A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "B1"),
              score=c(3,4,5,3,6,5))

> df1
  ID score
1 A1     3
2 A1     4
3 A1     5
4 B1     3
5 B1     6
6 B1     5
```

The outcome should look like this. Note that the elements in `score` become nodes that are linked with ties if they are held by the same `ID`.

```
> el
  X Y
1 3 4
2 3 5
3 4 5
4 3 6
5 6 5
```

The original `df1` has roughly 30 million observations from which an edgelist needs to be calculated frequently.

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: @r2evans No - at this point not.

Comment: Is this 'just' combinations of two by group? Is so, see a possible duplicate: [Faster version of combn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828301/faster-version-of-combn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popular (and efficient) tool for "large-ish" data is `data.table`:

```
library('data.table')
DT <- as.data.table(df1)
unique(DT[,as.data.frame(t(combn(score,2))), by = "ID"][,ID := NULL,])
#    V1 V2
# 1:  3  4
# 2:  3  5
# 3:  4  5
# 4:  3  6
# 5:  6  5
```

Comment: This code works great for the example data. However, in the original data I get the following error: "negative length vectors are not allowed". Does this, perhaps, correspond to the fact that some `ID` have only one score?

Comment: Likely, yes. Since those cannot contribute to edges, should they be filtered out before this process?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Indeed, because they don't produce edges.

Comment: `unique(DT[,if (.N>1) as.data.frame(t(combn(score,2))), by = "ID"][,ID := NULL,])` ?

Comment: This works great, @r2evans. I'm keeping this question unanswered for a bit so others can suggest an approach too. Will close it soon. Thank you!

Comment: Don't discount using Henrik's suggested `combnPrim`, as well, it looks to be drop-in compatible.

Comment: Does `unique(d[d, on = .(ID, score < score), .(x = x.score, y = i.score), nomatch = 0L])` work?