# R: cross join column on itself excluding symmetric results

Tags: r, merge, data.table, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have a data table `init` that looks like this:

```
> init
+---+
| id|       
+---+
|  a|
+---+
|  b|
+---+
|  c|
+---+
```

I want to obtain all pairs for `id` column, so I need to cross join the `init` data table on itself. Additionally, I want to exclude equal and symmetric results (in my case `a,b == b,a`, etc.).

Desired output is:

```
+---+---+
|id1|id2|
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
|  a|  c|
|  b|  c|
+---+---+
```

How can this be done with the `data.table` approach?

Full cross join can be implemented as
`full_cj <- CJ(init$id, init$id)`:

```
+---+---+
| V1| V2|
+---+---+
|  a|  a|
|  a|  b|
|  a|  c|
|  b|  a|
|  b|  b|
|  b|  c|
|  c|  a|
|  c|  b|
|  c|  c|
+---+---+
```

But how can I remove symmetrical and identical results from the output?
My real data is huge, so I'm looking for an efficient solution.

Comment: Some data.table options here: [faster version of combn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828301/faster-version-of-combn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a non equi join after converting to factor

```
dt[, id2:=as.factor(id)][dt, on=.(id2>id2),nomatch=0,.(id, id2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, this can be achieved as well using base R by

```
init[, .(id1 = rep(id, rev(seq_along(id) - 1L)),
         id2 = unlist(lapply(-seq_along(id), tail, x = id)))]
```

#### Benchmark

As the OP has mentioned

> My real data is huge, so I'm looking for an efficient solution.

here is a benchmark comparing

- **cj**: CJ() with subsequent filtering
- **sj**: [langtang's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624399/3817004) *non-equi self-join*
- **rp**: above base R approach using `rep()` and `tail()`

for problem sizes (length of input vector) of 10, 100, 1000, and 10k rows. Note that for the 10k case the result contains nearly *50 million combinations*. So available memory is a limiting factor.

Note that `bench::mark()` verifies that all approaches return the same result.

```
library(bench)
library(data.table)
bm <- press(
  n_id = 10^(4:1),
  {
    init0 <- data.table(id = sprintf("%09i", seq(n_id)))
    cat(sprintf("Number of combinations in result: %g\n", (n_id-1)*n_id/2))
    mark(
      rp = {
        init <- copy(init0)
        init[, .(id1 = rep(id, rev(seq_along(id) - 1L)),
                 id2 = unlist(lapply(-seq_along(id), tail, x = id)))]
      },
      sj = {
        init <- copy(init0)
        init[, id2 := as.factor(id)][
          init, on = .(id2 > id2), nomatch = 0, .(id1 = as.character(id2), id2 = id)]
      },
      cj = {
        init <- copy(init0)
        init[, CJ(id1 = id, id2 = id)][id1 < id2]
      },
      check = function(x, y) {
        tmp <- all.equal(x, y, check.attributes = FALSE)
          if (!isTRUE(tmp)) {
            cat(tmp, "\n")
            str(x)
            str(y)
          }
        tmp
      },
      min_iterations = 1L
    )
  }
)

bm
```

> ```
>    expression  n_id      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result   memory  time 
>    <bch:expr> <dbl> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>   <list>  <lis>
>  1 rp         10000     1.8s     1.8s    0.556     2.05GB   0.556      1     1       1.8s <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
>  2 sj         10000    2.87s    2.87s    0.348     2.24GB   0.696      1     2      2.87s <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
>  3 cj         10000   49.29s   49.29s    0.0203    3.17GB   0.0203     1     1     49.29s <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
>  4 rp          1000  22.11ms  22.53ms   44.2      21.15MB   2.10      21     1   475.58ms <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
>  5 sj          1000  18.28ms  18.88ms   52.4      23.19MB   2.02      26     1   496.27ms <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
>  6 cj          1000 542.97ms 542.97ms    1.84     32.53MB   0          1     0   542.97ms <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
>  7 rp           100   1.46ms   1.52ms  651.      285.94KB   6.56     298     3   457.53ms <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
>  8 sj           100   2.14ms   2.21ms  450.      406.48KB   4.24     212     2   471.37ms <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
>  9 cj           100   6.92ms   6.97ms  143.      431.23KB   0         72     0   504.44ms <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
> 10 rp            10  679.8µs 738.38µs 1343.       66.34KB   6.60     610     3   454.25ms <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
> 11 sj            10   1.71ms   1.81ms  552.      156.17KB   4.22     262     2   474.47ms <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
> 12 cj            10 915.48µs 967.99µs 1029.      100.83KB   4.21     489     2   475.13ms <data.t… <Rprof… <ben…
> ```

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

#### Conclusion

`cj` is magnitudes slower than the other 2 approaches for larger use cases while `rp` is on a par with `sj` but allocates slightly less memory.