# Subtract all vector pairs

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata

I have a matrix of size 2000 X 700.
I want to subtract all possible pairs of rows.
If `x_i` represent a row then I want to compute: `x_1-x_2, x_1-x_3, ..., x_2-x_3,...`

Example:

```
mat 
1 2 3
5 3 2
1 1 6
```

My output should be

```
x_1 - x_2: -4 -1  1
x_1 - x_3:  0  1 -3
x_2 - x_3:  4  2 -4
```

I tried using a loop, but it takes too long.
Is there an efficient way to compute this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Those are not all possible pairs of rows though; only half. How do you define the pairs you want and the order they should be in? (e.g. you seem to want row1 - row2 but not row2 - row1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively fast approach would be to pre-define an index list and then use it on the data, set to `data.table`. The whole operation should finish in under a minute for a matrix of 2000 x 700.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(mat)

rows <- nrow(mat)
idx <- as.matrix(rbindlist(lapply(1:(rows - 1), function(x) 
  rbindlist(lapply((x + 1):rows, function(y) list(x, y)))))) # takes approx. 6 secs on my crappy system for 2000 x 2000 combinations
idx
     V1 V2
[1,]  1  2
[2,]  1  3
[3,]  2  3

mat[idx[, 1], ] - mat[idx[, 2], ] # takes approx. 12 secs for 700 columns, see below if there's a memory error "Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)"
   V1 V2 V3
1: -4 -1  1
2:  0  1 -3
3:  4  2 -4
```

If the data is very wide, the subtraction operation may not fit into memory due to the vectorized nature. A solution is to split the operation into smaller chunks by cycling through the indices, e.g.

```
rbindlist(apply(
  cbind(unique(floor(c(1, seq(1, nrow(idx), length.out=10)[2:9] + 1))), 
        unique(floor(seq(1, nrow(idx), length.out=10)[2:10]))), 1, function(x)
  mat[idx[x[1]:x[2], 1],] - mat[idx[x[1]:x[2], 2],]))
         V1 V2 V3 V1 V2 V3 V1 V2 V3 V1
      1: -4 -1  1 -4 -1  1 -4 -1  1 -4
      2:  0  1 -3  0  1 -3  0  1 -3  0
      3:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
      4: -4 -1  1 -4 -1  1 -4 -1  1 -4
      5:  0  1 -3  0  1 -3  0  1 -3  0
     ---                              
1998996:  4  1 -1  4  1 -1  4  1 -1  4
1998997:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1998998:  0 -1  3  0 -1  3  0 -1  3  0
1998999: -4 -2  4 -4 -2  4 -4 -2  4 -4
1999000: -4 -1  1 -4 -1  1 -4 -1  1 -4
```

##### Data

```
mat <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 5L, 1L), V2 = c(2L, 3L, 1L), V3 = c(3L, 
2L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use `combn`

```
combn(row.names(m1), 2, function(x) m1[x[1],] - m1[x[2],])
```

Comment: it works. but still too slow for my data size. it will take a few hours that way

Comment: @ari6739 `combn` is more faster than expand.grid or expand_grid or outer as those will do twice the number of comparisons

Comment: @ari6739 you may try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828301/faster-version-of-combn) faster option

Answer (score 0):

Another use of `combn` (along with `asplit`)

```
> t(combn(asplit(mat, 1), 2, function(x) do.call(`-`, x)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -4   -1    1
[2,]    0    1   -3
[3,]    4    2   -4
```